# the location of two points group with the same coordinates are not overlaped

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, point, overlapping-features

[image][image]I have two points data with the same coordinates, i add one of them by adding from Excel file and other one from CAD file, but in Arcmap the should be overlapped but it is not working. i selected the same projection system for them but still i can not solve this problem. please help me.
for eg. the green point is the point which i used GO TO XY and the blue one which is selected is the point selected from attributive table. i selected the same coordinate system for them but still the locations are so different.

Comment: They are not overlapping, because you can see them not overlapping (eg they are both in a totally difference position) or when you run a kind of spatial join it fails?

Comment: It's likely that one of them is not in the coordinate reference system you chose for it. You must use the data's current coordinate system. ArcMap can project the data on-the-fly to the other's coordinate system (If the geographic CRS aka datums are different, you might need to set a transformations). Please post an example from each dataset plus the coordinate system you think they're in.

Comment: i added picture of coordinate system and screen shoot of my work. thanks for reply. i really need for help.

Comment: thanks for your replies, actually i had some mistakes of excel file, i entered x for y and y for x. after checking the excel file i realized the problem.